I am trying to add ALT text to images inside a pdf programatically
I have the ALT text generated just need to add it somehow to the images under the figure tag. A little background - I want to my my pdf accessible to the WCAG 2.1 AA standards and i am using adobe autotag feature to tag the pdf. It tags the images as /figure. I can totally extract the figures and generate alt text but I cant find a way to embed or add that alt text to the image and make it WCAG 2.1 AA compliant. I ultimately also want to add this to a lambda function in AWS. Is there any way I could do so? Thank you!
I tried using multiple open source libraries pikepdf,pymupdf, and some more and also tried converting the pdf to html or xml but the issue with that is the pdf cant be converted back exactly to what it was. I also tried adding it directly in code but the file goes corrupt.

how you generated ALT Text which is following standards WCAG 2.1. Can you share code or solution link please ?

Github
It would be under the javascript_docker. @AakashGoel

The MCID for Alt text is either allocated at time of PDF generation (so for this WEB.HTML page by the browsers PDF generator), or can be easily be manually assigned in a GUI, when checking for the other human verified content. Thus Acrobat pre-flight is the simplest and easiest point to index Alt Text in the mandatory  PDF/AU post production.
In a web page there is a 1:1 direct relationship the alt= is directly combined with the img src. That direct association is not maintained in a PDF.
<div class="gravatar-wrapper-32">
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f50f5b351c1d07d2a5a8f023e1731768?s=64&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG&amp;f=y&amp;so-version=2"
alt="Aryan Khanna's user avatar"
width="32" height="32" class="bar-sm"></div>

Attempting to add all the production interconnected components inside a PDF stream is usually fraught with  problems, since all existing file components need re indexing & renumbering, thus becomes a massive slow internal task.

To add the required object and all it's dependents or ancestors (Parent = 119) and or any children objects midway through a PDF is not easy. This is object 120 of 156. the image can be anywhere in the file as the image and /Alt text are not directly related, but just numbers in a page index. Actually in this case, the image was placed way back as document number 11 object.
120 0 obj
<</Type /StructElem /S /Figure /Alt (Aryan Khanna's user avatar) /P 119 0 R /K [ << /Type /MCR /Pg 2 0 R /MCID 34 >> ] /ID (node00000026) >>
endobj

How to place the Tag is find the image number and look for it in the page contents here it is added as /X11.
/X11 Do

now inject the related Tag /MCID 34 number before it
/P<</MCID 34>>BDC
/X11 Do

That is where the link to a tag is manually placed before the correct image as a child reference. So it will be seen as a tag for an image.

However since EVERY PDF needs AT LEAST two manual visual checks to verify images, it is easiest to check the image alt data at the same time.


Thank you so much for answering this question and it gives me a lot more depth understanding of whats happening inside the pdf. I tried doing it in a similar way as I was trying to automate a lot of stuff for fixing the pdf. So I use the adobe autotag feature that mostly tags the images as a /FIGURE tag> I am adding the code that I used in the answer my question tab. Thank you so much @KJ for responding. It really helped me get insight on whats happening inside the pdf and how the structure looks like!

So I used pdf-lib in node.js to find the answer for this solution—also Special thanks to KJ for giving me a path. I used adobe api for autotagging first and then used pdflib for post-processing of adding alt tags which I would be generating through LLM. It was easier for me to reference it back through objid, otherwise normal ID would also work great with this. I am still working on it fully and hopefully in a few weeks would add a github link if anyone would like to give any feedback and help contribute to this project!
const pdfLib = require('pdf-lib');
const fs = require('fs').promises;

async function modifyPDF() {
    async function generateAltText(objId) {
        try {
          const json_file = await fs.readFile('output/ExtractTextTableInfoWithFiguresTablesRenditionsFromPDF/extract2024-07-30T14-39-57/structuredData.json', 'utf8');
          const data = JSON.parse(json_file);
    
      // Check if the object ID exists in the JSON
      if (altTexts[objId]) {
        return altTexts[objId];
      } else {
        return `Generated alt text for object ${objId}`;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error reading JSON file:", err);
      return `Generated alt text for object ${objId}`;
    }
  }

  

try {
    const pdfPath = '../output/AutotagPDF/what_is_fair_use_2018_Original.pdf.pdf';
    const pdfData = await fs.readFile(pdfPath);
    const pdfDoc = await pdfLib.PDFDocument.load(pdfData);

pdfDoc.context.enumerateIndirectObjects().forEach(([pdfRef, pdfObject]) => {
  if (pdfObject instanceof pdfLib.PDFDict) {
    const type = pdfObject.lookup(pdfLib.PDFName.of('Type'))?.encodedName;
    const structType = pdfObject.lookup(pdfLib.PDFName.of('S'))?.encodedName;

    if (structType === "/Figure") {
      const objId = `${pdfRef.objectNumber}-${pdfRef.generationNumber}`;
      const altText = pdfObject.lookup(pdfLib.PDFName.of('Alt'))?.value;

      if (!altText) {
        const newAltText = generateAltText(objId);
        pdfObject.set(pdfLib.PDFName.of('Alt'), pdfLib.PDFString.of(newAltText));
        pdfObject.set(pdfLib.PDFName.of('Contents'), 

pdfLib.PDFString.of(newAltText));
            console.log(`Updated Alt text for figure with Object ID: ${objId}`);
          } else {
            console.log(`Figure found with Object ID: ${objId}, Alt text already exists: ${altText}`);
          }
        }
      }
    });

    const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
    await fs.writeFile("your-pdf-document-accessible.pdf", pdfBytes);
    console.log("PDF modification complete. Output saved to your-pdf-document-accessible.pdf");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error processing PDF:", err);
  }
}

modifyPDF().catch(err => console.error(err));

